# How do you detect blank lines in Fortran?

Tags: input, fortran, whitespace

Given an input that looks like the following:

```
123
456
789

42
23
1337

3117
```

I want to iterate over this file in whitespace-separated chunks in Fortran (any version is fine). For example, let's say I wanted to take the average of each chunk (e.g. mean(123, 456, 789) then mean(42, 23, 1337) then mean(31337)).

I've tried iterating through the file normally (e.g. READ), reading in each line as a string and then converting to an int and doing whatever math I want to do on each chunk. The trouble here is that Fortran "helpfully" ignores blank lines in my text file - so when I try and compare against the empty string to check for the blank line, I never actually get a .True. on that comparison.

I feel like I'm missing something basic here, since this is a typical functionality in every other modern language, I'd be surprised if Fortran didn't somehow have it.

Comment: You should show your code. When you read a string which you then convert to a number, Fortran certainly won't convert a blank line to a number for you. An error condition should occur. But for actual details you must show the code and not describe it in words.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing `read *, string` instead of `read '(A)', string` but we do really need to see your code to be able to answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using so-called "list-directed" input (format = '*'), Fortran does special handling to spaces, commas, and blank lines.

To your point, there's a feature which is using the `BLANK` keyword with `read`

```
read(iunit,'(i10)',blank="ZERO",err=1,end=2) array
```

You can set:

- `blank="ZERO"` will return a valid zero value if a blank is found;
- `blank="NULL"` is the default behavior that skips blank/returns an error depending on the input format.

If all your input values are positive, you could use `blank="ZERO"` and then use the location of zero values to process your data.

EDIT as @vladimir-f has correctly pointed out, you not only have blanks in between lines, but also after the end of the numbers in most lines, so this strategy will not work.

You can instead load everything into an array, and process it afterwards:

```
program array_with_blanks
      integer :: ierr,num,iunit
      integer, allocatable :: array(:)
   
  open(newunit=iunit,file='stackoverflow',form='formatted',iostat=ierr)
      allocate(array(0))
      do
         read(iunit,'(i10)',iostat=ierr) num
         if (is_iostat_end(ierr)) then
            exit
         else
            array = [array,num]
         endif
      end do
      close(iunit)
      print *, array
end program
```

Comment: This sounds really dangerous. If there happens to be any trailing blank in the data files, the the values will be corrupted. Also, your format is likely to fail because the lines will be too short. And if they are not, you will read extra trailing zeros.

Comment: If there are any extra blanks, the numeric values will be corrupted. If there are no extra blanks, the read will fail. If there is just an empty line with no blanks, the read will fail. Notice that the word "blank" is used here with tho different meanings. An informal one for a "blank line" in the question and a formal one by the standard - referring to the "space" character.

Comment: My guess is the user wants to run some `sum(data)/count(data>0)`, it could have a million trailing blanks, I don't understand.

Comment: A trailing blank is a blank behind the numeric character. E.g. a string `1  ` has one numeric character and rwo trailing blanks. The rest of read with i3 and blank=zero will be 100 instead of 1 That is the purpose of this modifier. You use `i10` so either there are enough trailing blanks and the numbers will be very big, or there are not, the lines are too short and the read will fail. I stress that two very different meanings of the word "blank" are being mixed up here and highly suggest to test your code.

Comment: Ok now I see what you mean. You're right. The input lines have blanks also after each numeric string, not only in between lines.

Comment: I think you are still missing the point. A blank is the space ` ` character. Not any end-of-line or similar. I do not actually see any blank at all in the data shown in the question.

Comment: I mean line 1 in the example is `123 `  so it would be read as `1230` with the blank=zero keyword

Comment: It would be, if it were `123 `, but I do not actually see any trailing blank on that line.

Answer (score 2):

Just read each line as a character (but note Francescalus's comment on the format). Then read the character as an internal file.

```
program stuff
   implicit none
   integer io, n, value, sum
   character (len=1000) line

   n = 0
   sum = 0
   io = 0
   open( 42, file="stuff.txt" )
   do while( io == 0 )
      read( 42, "( a )", iostat = io ) line
      if ( io /= 0 .or. line == "" ) then
         if ( n > 0 ) print *, ( sum + 0.0 ) / n
         n = 0
         sum = 0
      else
         read( line, * ) value
         n = n + 1
         sum = sum + value
      end if
   end do

   close( 42 )

end program stuff
```

```
456.000000    
467.333344    
3117.00000
```